# Objective C multiline UILabel is not working

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

> Here I have attached the scenario of my issue.
>   Current View

[image]

> Here Top Title is a bit long string. But my view is shown partially.
>   Here I added the storyboard properties that I used for my UILabel.

[image]
[image]

> Can someone suggest a solution to make this UiLabel as multilined one ?

Comment: change the line-break to *word-wrap*.

Comment: Word wrap is only for when you specify the number of lines. A variable number of lines (ie 0) requires you keep line break set to truncate tail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a multi-line label with a fixed font size, if that label is constrained to a certain height.

Either the height needs to scale to allow more lines at that fixed font size, or the font size needs to scale down to fit all the text in.

If neither are possible, then the text will be truncated.

If your label is constrained to a certain height, then you can change the `Autoshrink` setting from `Fixed font size` to `Minimum font size` and specify the smallest size that you will allow the font to shrink to in order to accommodate  longer strings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the relation of constraint height: **Greater than or equal**

[image]